# Android recreate Fragment onBackPressed

Tags: android

I have two activities and one fragment in my app. The first activity, `MainActivity`, is used to hold the fragment. It contains an `ActionBarSherlock` `ActionBar` and the fragment, `WFrag`. `WFrag` opens up the second activity, `SettingsActivity`, when you press a button. In `SettingsActivity`, you can choose settings that affect the behavior of `WFrag`. Naturally, I want the `onBackPressed()` method to go back to `WFrag` and update it with the user's new settings. My question is: how do you make it so that when you go back (via the back button) from `SettingsActivity`, you recreate (call `onCreate()` again) `WFrag`?

Comment: override onBackPressed or add the update in onStart/onResume

Comment: That did it, thank you!
Any way to mark a comment as the best answer?

Comment: Try the answer of GoodLife on the given link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank/20340492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. override onBackPressed 
   or
2. add the update in onStart/onResume

Answer (score 1):

First you have to override onBackPressed() of SettingActivity.

Second when you start second activity i.e SettingActivity from MainActivity you have to clear Stack of previous activity in this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Same goes for SettingActivity in onBackPressed() method you have to run your MainActivity in this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if you are redirecting to MainActivity from button click you can use above code for same.