# How to close second activity including a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `MainActivity` where I start (via button click) another second activity:

```
val intent = Intent(activity, SecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

In that `SecondActivity` I inflate a `SecondFragment`.

When I:

1. Tap button to start `SecondActivity`
2. Automatically, in its onCreate() `SecondFragment` is inflated
3. When I want to go back to MainActivity by tapping back button, I get a white blank screen (I guess it deflates SecondFragment, but SecondActivity still running?!).
4. I have to press back button another second time, to actually go back to `MainActivity`

How can go from SecondFragment (--> SecondActivity) --> MainActivity with pressing just once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Fragment on back button pressed Activity is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank)

Comment: your question is related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340303/in-fragment-on-back-button-pressed-activity-is-blank/34025775

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Directly Goto MainActivity.java add this method to SecondActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish(); 
}
```

Comment: This is redundant. The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` already does exactly this (call `finish()`). Overriding the method and providing this implementation is 100% redundant. It accomplishes NOTHING.